# CSS animation works on JSFiddle on Chrome but not on Chrome on localhost

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, css-animations

Really weird problem.

When I copy paste the code from this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timrpeterson/4FMyA/26/ into my localhost server, the animation of the flames moving all around works on Firefox but not on Chrome. Also, the JSFiddle animates the flames on Chrome.

The error I'm getting on Chrome on localhost is `invalid property value`.

Anyone have any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: have you added `prefixfree.min.js` in your localhost ?

Comment: Thanks that did it! Please feel free to add this as an answer and I will upvote and accept. There is still something which doesn't make sense, though. JSFiddle and my localhost work differently using the **same** browser, Chrome. This must be a browser bug with `iframes` or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the browsers needs prefix to run the css3 animation by adding [**prefixfree.min.js**](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js) you animation work

for eg

```
-webkit- /* for chorme */
-moz- /* for mozilla */
-o- /* opera */
```

eg

```
-webkit-animation-delay:0s;
   -moz-animation-delay:0s;
     -o-animation-delay:0s;
        animation-delay:0s;
```

this plugin generate the prefix

Comment: Though I accepted this answer, there remains **two** significant issues: 1) How to make this work without adding a prefixing JS file. It would be nice to have a CSS only solution for several reasons, most significantly because the JS plugin doesn't correct the CSS in a way that is visually apparent to the developer. Meaning, the developer doesn't learn what the problem was.  2) why this works on JSFiddle on Chrome, but not on my localhost. As its the **same browser** both times, this could mean there is a bug with Chrome.